# Addon/plugin "Unplug", is it safe?

Tags: security, add-on

I tried the add-on named "Unplug", it works fine. But is it safe to use the "Unplug" add-on within Tor to catch streaming ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

any new addons are *potentially* detectable, so it *potentially* makes your fingerprint more specific. The safety of using an add-on is **totally and only** depends on the safety/leak-free specs of the particular add-on.

Comment: In other words, who knows.

Comment: generally, yes. A code review for that add-on is the "thing to do to find it out".